# Orbot not starting on rooted Samsung Galaxy S4 (Verizon)

Tags: root-access, samsung-galaxy-s-4, tor

I have recently rooted my Samsung Galaxy S4 (Verizon) using the method found [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/49767/28670).

I am trying to run Orbot(Tor) with the Tor Everything option enabled.

The application will not get past "Orbot is starting...". I am connected to WiFi and am on Verizon's service.

Unfortunately I had not tested this prior to rooting so I am not sure if the problems lies with running on an S4 or running on a rooted S4.

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall Orbot and have not had any luck.

I have tried to connect to 4G instead of WiFi, no change.

I have tried to turn off the Request Root Access, no change.

What is causing Orbot to not connect to the Tor Network?

Answer (score 1):

I just installed Orbot awhile ago, and I got it working on my rooted **Samsung Galaxy S4**. You need to set the proxy for your APN.

Go to `System Settings > More networks > Mobile networks > APN`. Open your existing APN, and take note of the settings. You need to make a clone of this APN (so that you will still have the original APN, and have another APN that goes through TOR). Go back to the APNs page, and create a new APN, copying the settings from the other APN.

Then, set these:

- Proxy: localhost
- Port: 8118

After that, make sure you select the newly-created APN as your new APN. Your network will refresh in a bit. Open your browser and open `check.torproject.org`. If it was successful, you should see something like this:

[image]

**WARNING:** If you use the GMail app (or in my case, Kaiten configured with my GMail), it may detect unauthorized access, and you may be asked to reset your GMail password online.

Comment: The option to add a new APN is grayed out and I can't select it. Do you know why that would be?

Comment: @TronicZomB I have no idea. But can you edit the Proxy and Port though?

Comment: No... I'm trying to figure out why I can't add an APN.

Comment: @TronicZomB Let me rephrase my question: Can you change the Proxy and Port of your existing and current APN?

Comment: That's what I thought you were asking and no I can not change that. I can change the name of the APN, that's it.

Comment: @TronicZomB That's weird. Maybe your network provider locked down the APNs so you couldn't add or change them? I've no idea though. I also have an S4 that's locked for use with a specific network provider, but I can add APNs.

Comment: I'm on Verizon if that makes any difference. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @TronicZomB I'm from the Philippines. So, might be a different case.

Comment: @TronicZomB You're welcome, bro.

Answer (score 0):

If you deny superuser access it works. At least on my VZW S4 it does.

Comment: But then it won't Tor Everything will it...?